# Ошибки линковщика Visual Studio + Qt + opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opencv

Пытаюсь создать в Visual Studio 2015 Qt проект и подключить к нему opencv. Отдельно и та, и другая библиотеки работают, но в одном проекте это вызывает кучу ошибок линковщика.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __thiscall QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QBEPAUQMetaObject@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall MainWindow::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MainWindow@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)   QtOP    C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\QtOP\QtOP\moc_qtop.obj  1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void
__thiscall QWidget::dragEnterEvent(class QDragEnterEvent *)" (?dragEnterEvent@QWidget@@MAEXPAVQDragEnterEvent@@@Z)  QtOP    C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\QtOP\QtOP\qtop.obj  1
```

И еще 116 ошибок в этом роде.
Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Очень похоже, что для каких то классов, которые наследуются от QObject, не добавили `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: Q_OBJECT добавлен, пробовала удалить и добавить заново, удалять папку debug, не помогло

Comment: Да, такое бывает. Сам наблюдал. Помогает сделать "run qmake" с меню (я пользуюсь QtCreator).

Comment: Не очень поняла, что значит с меню?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mm3N4.png

Comment: Вы используете [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](http://doc.qt.io/vs-addin/)?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы не подключили все требуемые `lib` файлы к проекту, при этом они подключены в ваших "отдельных проектах". В свойствах проекта, `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` пропишите либы для qt и/или opencv. Глянуть какие именно можно в отдельно работающих проектах.

Comment: судя по выводу линковщика, проблема похоже не в opencv. Но все может быть.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы не подключили к проекту moc_*.cpp файлы, которые генерятся для каждого класса отнаследованного от QObject. Обычно они находятся в тоже директории, что и сами классы. [Подробнее о moc файлах](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html)

Comment: как это сделать? Make Rules?

Comment: Просто добавить файлы в проект Visual Studio. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Не помогло. Там были эти файлы

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести весь список ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Для компилирования в VS классов, наследованых от QObject необходимо для заголовочного файла явно указать компилятор:

- В обозревателе проектов жмете правой кнопкой на хидере созданного класса
- Открываете properties.
- Item type выбираете custom build tool. Жмете Aplly
- Слева появится пункт custom build tool
- Там заполняете:

QTDIR32 - пусть к Qt, например c:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013\

```
Command line:  $(QTDIR32)\bin\moc.exe -I"..\..\common" %(Identity) -o    tmp\moc_%(Filename).cpp 

Description: MOC: $(QTDIR32)\bin\moc.exe    -I"..\..\common" %(Identity) -o tmp\moc_%(Filename).cpp 

Outputs: tmp\moc_%(Filename).cpp
```

- Жмете Ok
- Снова правой кнопкой мыши по хэдеру и пункт Compile.